# F# Int * Int confusion

Tags: types, f#, tuples

Firsly, I'd just like to state, I am completely new to this language and as of right now it seems extremely strange to me (As a Java/C# user).

I'm currently doing a uni project whereby I have to navigate a grid using pathfinding *(Not even close to this point, will deal with it later down the line)*, I have created a 2d array with a size of 10x10 however I've found that I can store my current position by using something like **let mutable position = 0,0** which gives me a type of int * int.

This seems great to me as I can store my X and Y location easily, however I've run into a couple of issues with this

**1)** Get the individual values in the variable. I.E get my current X position or get my current Y position

**2)** Add to this variable so that I can move around the grid. I.E position <- position + (5, 5)

Again, I've only had a small amount of experience with this language so please be gentle though I seem to grasp the basics quite well.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: The type `int * int` means that the type is a [tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx) where both elements have the type `int`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann So I assume I really shouldn't be using tuples for current positioning. Could you advise something better suited?

Comment: Why not? What makes you think that?

Comment: I always solve this problem by declaring my own Vector2 type like so: `type Vector2 = { x: int; y: int}`. That way you can a) overload * using a static method and b) create an operator to construct vectors (say, @@)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the individual values in a variable by using the `fst` or `snd` functions like so (note that this only works when you have size 2 tuples):

```
let gridPos = 1, 2
//val gridPos : int * int = (1, 2)
let xPos = fst gridPos
//val xPos : int = 1
let yPos  = snd gridPos
//val yPos : int = 2
```

As for the 2nd question, you can overwrite the addition operator to allow for tuple of `int*int` addition like so:

```
let (+) a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
//val ( + ) : int * int -> int * int -> int * int
let newValue = gridPos + (2,5)
//val newValue : int * int = (3, 7)
```

That said you should generally avoid mutable state in F#...

Comment: I see, very helpful information but I can't help but think this isn't the approach I should take as it doesn't seem very efficient for simply holding positional data

Comment: I don't see any issue with holding the positional data in a tuple. But making tuples mutable is a kind of a no-no...

Comment: Could you explain as to why it's not smart to make it mutable? It seems kind of necessary in this application as I will have to have a loop later on actively changing the position (Via the pathfinding)

Comment: See that's the thing. Generally you don't need to do loops in F# because you can use recursion instead. And if state is important, you should pass in the state as a parameter in your recursive function. This article gives a short explanation for how you might do it for a simple example (the factorial): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/doriancorompt/2012/01/08/1-recursion-where-are-my-forwhile-loops/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for the help. I'll give that a read over and try and figure out how I wish to proceed.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what Ringil said, you can deconstruct a tuple using:

```
let xPos, yPos = gridPos
```

This is more terse/idiomatic in F#.

Comment: As a bonus, you can do this in places where you can't use `snd` like function parameters `let test = fun a (x,y) ->x*y` and then `test "ignore this" (1,2)`